# Nginx redirect a specific subdomain to specific location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I would like it so that when a user types `task-manager.example.com`, they are automatically redirected to `location /api/`  without having to type out the full path of `task-manager.example.com/api`. Only  `task-manager.example.com` should get redirected to `location /api/`

For `example.com` and `www.example.com`, I want all requests to be directed to `location /` regardless of whether the user types `example.com/api` or not. Any requests to `example.com/api` or `www.example.com/api` should be automatically redirected to `example.com/` or `www.example.com/`.

Can Nginx be configured to achieve this functionality?

Here is my current configuration:

```
server
{
    server_name example.com www.example.com task-manager.example.com;

    location /
    {
        # Frontend application
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
    }

    location /api/
    {
        # Backend application
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    }

    # some Certbot SSL configuration ...
}

server
{
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host/;
    } # managed by Certbo


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host/;
    } # managed by Certbo


    if ($host = task-manager.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host/api;
    } # managed by Certbo


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com task-manager.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by moving the `if conditions` to the relevant `location blocks`. This allowed me to specify redirects for specific hosts to go to specific URIs.

This is my new config:

```
server
{
    server_name example.com www.example.com task-manager.example.com;

    location /
    {
        if ($host = task-manager.example.com) {
            return 301 /api;
        }

        # Frontend application
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
    }

    location /api/
    {

        if ($host = www.example.com) {
            return 301 /;
        }

        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 /;
        }

        # Backend application
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    }

    # here is usually some Certbot SSL configuration ...
}

server
{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com task-manager.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```